# Select an element from a list of list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following object (I'm using JSON to display my data in this post).

I need to select the Year where VehicleClassID = 1 using LINQ C#.

**
[
{
"VehicleClassID": 1,
"VehicleClassName": "Economy ",
"dbo.Vehicles": [
{
"MakeID": 2,
"ModelID": 8,
"Year": 2019
},
{
"MakeID": 6,
"ModelID": 68,
"Year": 2019
},
{
"MakeID": 53,
"ModelID": 773,
"Year": 2020
}
]
},
{
"VehicleClassID": 2,
"VehicleClassName": "Luxury",
"dbo.Vehicles": [
{
"MakeID": 2,
"ModelID": 8,
"Year": 2020
},
{
"MakeID": 86,
"ModelID": 1157,
"Year": 2020
}
]
}
]**

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: You say "select *the* year" but there are several vehicles under the element with a VehicleClassID of 1. So, what should the result look like?

Answer (score 5):

You can use below query to get all years for your vehicle

```
var years = data.Where(x => x.VehicleClassID == 1) //filter
                .SelectMany(x => x.Vehicles)       //select all vehicles
                .Select(x => x.Year)               //select year from each vehicle
                .ToList()                          //return list of years
```

Comment: I can't see a generic type in the question! How would this code work?

Comment: @Kaj as the op says he as the "object" and the question is tagged c# we can assume there is an object to query. imo this answer is fine!

Comment: this is exactly my issue, thanks Alex Lê!

Answer (score 0):

Using [Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp) you can create your class to parse JSON:

```
namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class Vehicles
    {
        [JsonProperty("VehicleClassID")]
        public long VehicleClassId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("VehicleClassName")]
        public string VehicleClassName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("dbo.Vehicles")]
        public DboVehicle[] DboVehicles { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class DboVehicle
    {
        [JsonProperty("MakeID")]
        public long MakeId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ModelID")]
        public long ModelId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Year")]
        public long Year { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Vehicles
    {
        public static Vehicles[] FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Vehicles[]>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Vehicles[] self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

Then you can easily do:

```
var vehicles = Vehicles.FromJson(jsonString);
var v = vehicles.FirstOrDefault(ve => ve.VehicleClassId == 1);
if (v != null) {
    // Your array has multiple years, so I get the first
    var year = v.DboVehicles.FirstOrDefault()?.Year ?? 0;
}
```

Comment: Why a downvote? What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: I did not downvote, but I guess Deserialization is not the question here. I guess the question is actually purely about linq.

Comment: @FelixD. well, if this is the reason, how can we answer without seeing OP classes? We can just guess... and I guessed OP doesn't have anything :D